# Not able to resolve ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymongo'

Tags: python, mongodb, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I downloaded and installed mongoDB, ran mongod command on cmd as admin, did install mongodb and pymongo in anaconda however, keep getting this error when I `import pymongo`. Searched extensively on the same issue however, it does not really seem to help in my case. Don't understand why and what am I missing. I have python 3.7 on windows.

---

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 import pymongo

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymongo'

Comment: How did you install `pymongo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `pip install` with anaconda environments, it's imperative that you keep track of which interpreter you are using when installing:

```sh
pip -V # might output a different result than

python -m pip -V
```

The latter is definitely preferred when installing, as you know exactly which interpreter you are using, which will tie it to the correct instance of `pip`.

### Activate

If you have a `conda environment` configured, be sure to `conda activate <yourenv>` first, this way you can be sure that `pip` also installs packages there.

```sh
conda activate <yourenv>

python -m pip -V
# /path/to/yourenv/lib/pythonx.x/site-packages
```

Then, `python -m pip install pymongo` should work. Following that, you will want to double check that the env is activated when you run `jupyter notebook` as well. If you are in jupyter already, you can run the following to check:

```py
import sys

sys.path[-1]
'/path/to/yourenv/lib/pythonx.x/site-packages'
```

If this doesn't match where `yourenv` should be, then you probably didn't activate the environment. You'll need to stop jupyter, activate, then re-start the notebook.

Comment: Perfect! Apparently I was able to figure out easily on my home PC while I messed it up on my work PC. I am able to correct it following these steps. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

a common reason for this is that your are using multiple python versions (e.g. 2.X and 3.X)
Then it can happen that you install it for a different version than your are actually using.

Check your `site-packages` folder if it really contains pymongo

Answer (score 0):

I installed pymongo today using Anconda.

1. Go to  Start-> Anconda Navigator. Click on Environments. Search for pymongo in installed packages.
2. If pymongo doesnt exist in installed packages, do below:
3. From Start menu -> **Command Prompt(cmd)**, type below command:

   ```
     pip install pymongo
   ```
4. Assuming Anaconda 3 folder is in My computer -> C: -> Users -> Uuser name/admin. Right click on My computer -> properties.  A tab will open -> Advanced Systems settings-> Advanced tab go to Environmnet Variables at the bottom -> In system variables below, go to path, double click. Click on new and  Paste the path of your Anaocnda 3 folder there.
5. From Start Menu -> **Anaconda Prompt**, type below command:

   ```
     conda install pymongo
   ```

   It will ask you to select yes/no in the middle for packages. You can type Y if it asks and it will proceed.
6. Go to **Anconda Navigator** and **check** whether the pymongo is in **installed packages** or not after the successful execution of this command. If it is in the installed packages then your work is done.
7. Go to Anaconda Navigator -> Spyder or Jupyter notebooks and type import pymongo and start coding

`